# How to use AppComponent static variable in other component tempalte in Angular 8?

Tags: angular

I have the following tag in a template, this code is working fine:

```
<img [src]="'http://localhost:9050/api/files/' + some.id + '/folder/' + myFileName">
```

In AppComponent I have the following static var:

```
public static SOME_SERVICE_API = 'http://localhost:9050/api';
```

What I'm trying to achieve is somthing like this:

```
<img [src]="'AppComponent.SOME_SERVICE_API' + '/files/' + some.id + '/folder/' + myFileName">
```

But the AppComponent is undefined, so it's look like I need to import first the compoenent
somehow and also change the template to make it work but while searching for solution, couldn't
find one.

import { AppComponent } from 'src/app/app.component'; is not enough.

Comment: you can only refer to the corresponding component's fields. so doing somthing like `AppComponent = AppComponent` inside of another component should help

Comment: adding  public API = AppComponent.SOME_SERVICE_API and using API in the rempalte, I am able to see the url with the resolved path. thanks. but the problem is that the pipe doen't work so I'll create another question cause it is something else.